# Media query height used as width in min-width

Tags: css, media-queries

I've done a responsive mobile first home page and I've written a media query for laptops (min-width: 768px), now I'm trying the same thing for desktop devices (min-width: 1080px) but it prevent from working the laptop's query, because for some reason the min-width 1080px is affected also by the height, in fact when i use a 1366x768 window wokrs only the 1080p's query, but if I use a 1079x768px window work with the 768p's query. I've also noticed the if I put the desktop's query before the laptop's query it doesn't work anymore. Here's the code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px), screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
    div#divRegistrazione {
        margin-top: 3vh;
    }
    input[type=text],
    input[type=password] {
        padding: 0.7em 1.5vw;
    }
    input[type=date] {
        font-size: 2em;
        padding: 0.2em 1.5vw;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    input[type=text],
    input[type=password] {
        padding: 0.9em 1.5vw;
    }
    input[type=date] {
        font-size: 2em;
        padding: 0.45em 1.5vw;
    }
    div#divRegistrazione {
        margin-top: 6vh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard to picture, but I think your problem is how you are visualizing the screens sizes.  Because of the top media query, it will affect **everything** larger than 768px (min-width: 768px). This includes everything in your query of min-width: 1080px.

If your width is over 1080, it is being set in the first query, then being overwritten by your second query.

Also, I think the comma in the first query is tripping you up. 
Here is an example of how the media queries can override each other.  Notice how I dont need to call `.media_query_1` in the last query because it is still has a `min-width: 769px`.

Try looking at this in a new window and see how the queries react with one another.

```html
<style>
/*THIS ONE AFFECTS SCREENS SMALLER THAN 769PX */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #divRegistrazione {margin-top: 3vh;}
    input[type=text], input[type=password] {padding: 0.7em 1.5vw;}
    input[type=date] {font-size: 1em; padding: 0.2em 1.5vw;}

    .media_query_1 {display:block;}
    .media_query_2 {display:none;}
    .media_query_3 {display:none;}
}
/*THIS ONE AFFECTS ALL SCREENS LARGER THAN 768PX */
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #divRegistrazione {margin-top: 6vh;}
    input[type=text], input[type=password] {padding: 0.9em 1.5vw;}
    input[type=date] {font-size: 2em; padding: 0.45em 1.5vw;}

    .media_query_1 {display:none;}
    .media_query_2 {display:block;}
    .media_query_3 {display:none;}
}
/*THIS ONE AFFECTS ALL SCREENS LARGER THAN 1080PX, INCLUDING THE ABOVE MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    /*these override the classes in the above query */
    .media_query_2 {display:none;}
    .media_query_3 {display:block;}
    
}
</style>
<div id="divRegistrazione">
    <div class="media_query_1">SMALL SCREEN SIZE</div>
    <div class="media_query_2">MEDIUM SCREEN SIZE</div>
    <div class="media_query_3">LARGE SCREEN SIZE</div>
        <input type="text" name=""><br />
        <input type="password" name=""><br />
        <input type="date" name="">
</div>
```

Comment: @Fabi0_Z I have updated my answer so it might make more sense to you.  The media query divs should make it more clear what you will see and at what size.

Comment: Okk sorry if i reply so late, I've done some tests and I've figured out that i was using wrong sizes for the width, (i was using 1080px instead 1920px for Full HD monitors etc). Actually everything was already working fine. Thanks for help!